# Use window.getSelection() to get the selected text, the html and the css styles used to format and design the text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, copy

I want to be able to highlight or select and copy text from a webpage and when i paste it on a word document editor, it still retains its colors, links and background styles like it does in the webpage.

Basically a copy from browser page and paste in a document editor can solve this but i want to create a javascript function that does exactly this.

This is what I have done so far but i cannot get the complete html tags as well as the styles associated with it

```
function getSelectedText() {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
  content = range.cloneContents(),
     span = document.createElement('span');
  
  span.appendChild(content);
  var htmlContent = span.innerHTML;

  range.deleteContents();
  range.insertNode(span);
  
  return htmlContent

}
```

Comment: I don't think a word document editor is going to be able to read html. I'm sure it has it's own syntax for font, color, size, etc. What word document editor do you want to copy to?

Comment: @LukasSorensen if you copy a colored text on a webpage and paste it on a word document editor, you'd notice that the text in the word pasted in the word editor would still retain its text color and even text format